# Loading double to FPU with GCC (Inline assembler)

Tags: gcc, assembly, double, gnu-assembler, fpu

I've been trying to load a `double` to the FPU with `FLD` using GCC inline assembly.

Being not that familiar with the AT&T syntax and not having found anything on the web, I'd greatly appreciate your help.
My intention was to load the address of `a` to `EAX` and then do `FLD [EAX]`...

```
double atl(double a, int adr) {
    __asm ("movl ptr %0,%%eax"::"r"(a));
    __asm ("fld qword (%eax)");
    //.... some other code here
    __asm("movl ptr %0,%%eax"::"r"(a));
    __asm("fst qword (%eax)");
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Note that the compiler is allowed to reorder the assembly lines without respecting any semantics, if you don't use `asm volatile`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that.
Now the asm code doesn't really seem to work, do you have any suggestions? gcc says the operands would be invalid for the first and last line.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that register contents remain from one `asm` to another either.  If you have a sequence of instructions that must run together, make a single `asm` with all of them inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest is to use the [constraint "m"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints), to load from/save to a memory location:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double a = 0.78539816339744;
    asm ("fldl %0;"
         "fsin;"
         "fstpl %0" : "+m"(a));
    printf("sin(45°) = %f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The [modifier "+"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) tells the compiler that you want your input in that memory location and to output to the same location.

GCC is allowed to reorder your lines, but it will know the semantics of that line, and it will optimize accordingly.

A more difficult example, employing loading from other variables than that are to be written to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double sin_a, cos_a, a = 0.5;
    asm ("fldl %2;"
         "fsincos;"
         "fstpl %1;"
         "fstpl %0;" : "=m"(sin_a), "=m"(cos_a) : "m"(a));
    printf("sin(29°) = %f, cos(29°) = %f\n", sin_a, cos_a);
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/SuvpM.

<s>PS: I could not get GCC to load a **double** value, though, so I don't know if my answer is any use to you. :-(</s>

#### Update:

Got it: you need to append `s` (for single [32 bits], as in `flds`, floating-point load single), `l` (for double [64 bits]), or `t` (for long double [80 bits]) explicitely. My GCC 4.6.3 assumes a single value for every memory operand …

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Now some how loading a double worked for me, at least I'm not getting any errors and the value can be used in subsequent assembly code.

Comment: @MarcelL I solved the double load/store problem. See my update.

Comment: Perhaps a `"t"` clobber constraint is missing here?